# My SQL Server Express has gone nuts it seems, at times mounting db and others not

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I am not sure what's going on exactly as I can't establish a strict linear correlation between
events. But below you'll find my connection string, at times it works, other times when I open the app/project I am building (no changes made) it doesn't and gives me various errors and reasons.

```
<add name="EFDbContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\EFDbContext.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Errors include:

> Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog.

or

saying Amin-PC\Admin has no access rights (I am logged in admin)

Also when I try to add a new connection at times it will tell me I have no access rights or database already exists or just adds it normally!

I tried explicitly starting visual studio as administrator and this seemed to help with the denied access to the db issue.

Basically I don't know what the heck's going on.

Have recently started with .net and it has been easy coding for asp.net mvc framework until I got to interacting with underlying asp.net infrastructure, connection strings, outdated (noon-entity framework ready) membership provider etc.

And now don't know what's going on with the SQL Server Express edition that gets installed a long with VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be: since you already have a server instance (`.\SQLEXPRESS`) installed - attach your databases to the SQL Server Express instance, and then use them under their database name (instead of using the shaky `AttachDbFileName=` method).

So:

- launch your SQL Server Management Studio Express
- find your MDF files you want
- use Server > Attach Database to attach the MDF/LDF to the server - give it meaningful name
- from that point on - use the database **on the server** and don't attach MDF's on the fly....

Your connection string would then look something like:

```
server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourEFDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True
```

I find this method is typically much more reliable and predictable - the `AttachdbFileName=` and `User Instance=true` are supposed to be easier, but tend to be more confusing that anything else....

Answer (score 0):

Refer to SQL Server connection string samples [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).